# handling data on failure of invoking webhook url

Tags: webhooks

My SaaS product posts event notification as webhooks. This question is about handling the failure cases when I post to the webhook url.

In case of not receiving the 200 OK response code from the URL I post the event data, I mark that event notification as failed and start the retry process.  Currently I store the ID(s) of the data I have to send as part of event data and fetch it from the DB for every retry.

I just wanted to see how others handle this? One another thing I can think of is to store the actual payload(in JSON or XML format) in the DB and send that on each retry. But how do you expect the event receiver to handle the data sync issues that might arise because of this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to give the webhook receiver the option to choose whether or not to re-POST data when they register their endpoint with your service. I also highly recommend providing clear documentation how your service handles different response codes.

It might be worth notifying the endpoint admin via email of the sync issues. This is more of a nice to have, as they can also always ping their own service or POST test data regularly.

Also, consider this: What happens when *your* service fails. If sync is important, how does your service and the endpoint resolve that problem?

You didn't provide too much context for what kind of data you're POSTing and what precise sync issues you're afraid of. Can you share more?

**Edited**: Here's [how MailChimp handles this issue](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/). They're clearly in the same boat as you are.

> > > When an event occurs that you have turned on, we'll send a HTTP POST request to the URL you've specified. If that URL is not available or takes too long to respond (more than 15 seconds), we'll cancel the request and try again later. Retries are done at increasing intervals over the course of 1 hour and 15 minutes. Those time frames may be tweaked as we start to receive feedback from users.
> > >
> > > For each event we'll return various data based on the event. Below is a sample data for each event - you can also easily see this using the PostBin tool mentioned above. Generally speaking, you'll see each event has a type and a fired_at field to help you track the type of event and get a timestamp (in GMT!) for the event.